# Finding $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ (Negative Binomial Distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation

Suppose $Y \sim \text{NegBin}(n, p)$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty}y^2\binom{r+y-1}{y}p^rq^y$$
where $q = 1 - p$. Now since the $y = 0$ term adds nothing,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] &= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y^2\binom{r+y-1}{y}p^rq^y  \\
&= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}yr\binom{r+y-1}{y-1}p^rq^y \tag{1}\\
&= r\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y\binom{r+y-1}{y-1}p^rq^y \text{.} 
\end{align}$$
$(1)$ is true because
$$y\binom{r+y-1}{y} = \dfrac{(r+y-1)!}{(y-1)!(r-1)!} = \dfrac{r}{r}\left(\dfrac{(r+y-1)!}{(y-1)!(r-1)!}\right) = r\binom{r+y-1}{y-1}\text{.}$$
Set $z = y - 1$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] &= r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}(z+1)\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1} = r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}z\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1} + r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
I showed already that $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}z\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1} = \dfrac{rq}{p}\text{.}$$
I'm not sure how to find $$r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1}$$
after many tries. I believe it should be equal to $$\dfrac{qr(qr+q)}{p^2}$$
but I'm *really* not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), we get
\begin{align*}
r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1}&=
rp^rq\sum_{z=0}^\infty \binom{z+r}{z}q^z\\
&=\frac{rp^rq}{(1-q)^{r+1}}\\
&=\frac{rp^rq}{p^{r+1}}\\
&=\frac{rq}{p}
\end{align*}

Comment: Where did I mess up in my algebra? Obviously this doesn't match what I thought it should be. $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ should end up being $\dfrac{rq(1+rq)}{p^2}$.

Comment: @Clarinetist I didn't look at it, I just looked for your specific question which was this. If I notice anything, I will notify you.

Comment: @Clarinetist Also, do you have to do it this way? If you can, you can use results from a geometric distribution and arrive at these things quicker

Comment: At this point in the text, the geometric distribution and MGFs have not been introduced yet (which would make things MANY times easier).

Comment: @Clarinetist So you have to grind it this way huh. That's strange.

Comment: Your sum is right. I did $r\sum_{z=0}^{\infty}z\binom{r+z}{z}p^rq^{z+1}$ wrong.

Comment: @Clarinetist Great, glad you found it.